# Why smooth varieties are local complete?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Harri's book is used the fact that for any variety $V$ if it is smooth, then the diagonal $\Delta_V\subseteq V\times V$ is local complete intersection. Recall that a variety is local complete intersection if for every $p\in V$ there exists an affine neighbourhood $U$ such that the ideal of $V\cap U\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is generated by $n-d$ polynomials where $d$ is the local dimension of $V$ at $p$. I think that if $V$ is smooth, then $V$ itself is local complete intersection but I don't know why.

Comment: What is the relation between $V$ and $X$?

Comment: See Theorem 1.16 in Mumford's "Algebraic Geometry I: Complex Projective Varieties" for a nice proof (his proof works for an arbitrary field).